# Why is reading from a NumPY array so slow for a CDF file

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-iris

I have a simple netCDF file which has a cube of data i.e LAT, LONG ,TIME as 3 dimension and it stores Temperature. It's stored in the form of Masked Array in NumPy . Below code extracts it as CSV format. But its very slow for processing 20 MB file, i.e. for each iteration it takes 20 seconds, so totally I have 4 * 548 * 20 seconds = 43840 sec = 703 mins = 12 hours.

If you look at line which has comment TAKES_LONG_TIME , it takes more time. I believe for each cell there is a switch happening from Python to C code in NumPy. Not sure in the below scenario how I can resolve. Please advise. Thanks.

```py
# conda install -y -c conda-forge iris

import iris
import cf_units as unit
import numpy as np
import datetime
import urllib.request
from os import path


def make_data_object_name(dataset_name, year, month, day, hour, realization, forecast_period):
    template_string = "prods_op_{}_{:02d}{:02d}{:02d}_{:02d}_{:02d}_{:03d}.nc"
    return template_string.format(dataset_name, year, month, day, hour, realization, forecast_period)


def download_data_object(dataset_name, data_object_name):
    url = "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/" + dataset_name + "/" + data_object_name
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, data_object_name)  # save in this directory with same name


def load_data():
    filename = 'prods_op_mogreps-uk_20140101_03_02_003.nc'
    if not path.exists(filename):
        # obj_name = make_data_object_name('mogreps-uk', 2014, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3)
        download_data_object('mogreps-uk', filename)

    listofcubes = iris.load(filename)
    air_temps = listofcubes.extract('air_temperature')
    surface_temp = air_temps[0]
    dim_time, dim_lat, dim_long = "time", "grid_latitude", "grid_longitude"

    time_cords = surface_temp.coord(dim_time).points
    time_since = str(surface_temp.coord(dim_time).units)
    lat_cords = surface_temp.coord(dim_lat).points
    long_cords = surface_temp.coord(dim_long).points

    time_records = [str(unit.num2date(time_cords[i], time_since, unit.CALENDAR_STANDARD)) for i in
                    range(len(time_cords))]
    lat_records = [lat_cords[lat_recorded] for lat_recorded in range(len(lat_cords))]
    long_records = [long_cords[long_recorded] for long_recorded in range(len(long_cords))]

    print(len(time_records), len(lat_records), len(long_records))
    print(surface_temp.shape)
    data_size = len(surface_temp.shape)
    print(" File write start -->  ", datetime.datetime.now())
    with open(filename + '.curated', 'w') as filehandle:
        for t, time_record in enumerate(time_records):  # Iterate TIME - 4
            t_a = surface_temp[t] if data_size == 3 else surface_temp[t][0]
            for lat, lat_record in enumerate(lat_records):  # Iterate LAT - 548
                lat_a = t_a[lat]
                iter_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                lat_lines = list()
                for lng, long_record in enumerate(long_records):  # Iterate Long 421
                    data = str(lat_a[lng].data.min()) # TAKES_LONG_TIME
                    lat_lines.append(time_record + ',' + str(lat_record) + ',' + str(long_record) + ',' + data + '\n')
                filehandle.writelines(lat_lines)
                print(t, time_record, lat, lat_record, " time taken in seconds -> ",
                      (datetime.datetime.now() - iter_start_time).seconds)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_data()
```

Comment: to clarify a bit: how many lines are there to write in `filehandle.writelines(lat_lines)`? And from the code I'd infer that `lat_a[lng]` should already be a scalar if your data is time x lat x lon x temperature - so why call `.min()` in `lat_a[lng].data.min()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first read in your cubes using `iris.load`, the actual data arrays do not get loaded into memory (see [Real and lazy data](https://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/userguide/real_and_lazy_data.html) in the Iris User Guide).  Because you are slicing up your cube before accessing `subcube.data`, the actual loading is happening individually for each slice.  So you are going back and accessing the NetCDF file every time your "TAKES_LONG_TIME" line is executed.

To load everything into memory before you start your loops, simply add a line that says

```
surface_temp.data
```

This should speed things up, but may not be desirable depending how much memory you have available.  A compromise could be found by choosing a different level in your for loop to realise the data (i.e. `ta.data` or `la.data`).